Lead path misses labels and colors in Summer'24 sandbox
While doing regression tests in a Summer'24 sandbox, I came across this:

for multiple users (admin, non-admin), Chrome and Edge browsers. I couldn't find it in the Summer'24 known issues.
Anyone recognizing this?
Update 1: as soon as I changed the status to something else than the initial status, the path labels and colors became visible, for that user. For other users, still not.
Update 2: revisiting a freshly created lead, I came upon this error:

We don't use record types for Leads. I haven't seen this error before.

Do you still see this issue?

@Vinay 24 hours after I have seen it for the first time: yes, I still see the blank and colorless path labels.

This seem to be intermittent and gets fixed, it occurs in orgs where there is no custom record type is created for leads and the filter criteria for the lightning component involves the field "lead status"

Yes I am facing this issue as well. @Vinay this is happening to Case also but this behaviour is inconsistent. Is this due to recent release? If yes, is this under being fixed?

Yah behavior is inconsistent and can't be reproduce and this should be fixed now, will update if I have more details on this.
